# E possivel pegar dados do mês inteiro no postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Como faço para que a partir de um mês especifico eu consiga obter todos os dados gravado no banco: acho que se deve passar o ano / mês como parâmetro por exemplo variavel = "2016/10"; lembrando que o tipo do dado no banco e timestamp

```
  SELECT * FROM dados WHERE data_registro = variavel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opção 1: Utilização do `TO_CHAR`:

```
select * from dados where TO_CHAR(data_registro, 'MM/YYYY') = '01/2016'
```

Opção 2: Utilização com ranges:

```
select * from dados where data_registro >= '2016-01-01'::DATE 
and data_registro <= '2016-01-31'::DATE
```

Opção 3: Utilização do [overlaps](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html)

```
select * from dados where (data_registro, data_registro) 
OVERLAPS ('2016-01-01'::DATE, '2016-01-31'::DATE);
```

Opção 4: Com `Extract`:

```
select * from dados 
where 
Extract(month from data_registro) >= Extract(month from '2016-01-01'::DATE)
and Extract(month from data_registro) <= Extract(month from '2016-01-31'::DATE)
```

Opção 5: Utilização de `intervals` baseados em data corrente:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dados
WHERE  Extract(month from data_registro) >= Extract(month from Now())
AND    Extract(month from data_registro) <= Extract(month from Now() + Interval '20 day')
```

Comment: Fiz o teste aqui da primeira opção e funcionou, Perfeito!

Answer (score 1):

Só dando continuidade as opções já citadas

Opção com `date_trunc`

```
SELECT * FROM dados WHERE 
   date_trunc('month', data_registro) = date_trunc('month', '2015-03-01');
```

Neste caso o parametro pode ser qualquer data válida no mês, ele vai truncar ambos para o mesmo mês.

[Referência](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)

Answer (score 0):

Tem como usar `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT dados
FROM   tabela
WHERE  tabela.data BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-31'
```

Se o campo em questão for do tipo TIMESTAMP, dependendo do seu BD, deve-se lembrar de fazer o CAST (ex.: Postgres `tabela.data::DATE`)